# About the total boundedness of a given set in a complete Metric Space

Tags: real-analysis, compactness

So i haven't done this stuff in a really long time and i need some help to complete this proof.
I want to show: Let $(X,d)$ be a complete metric space and ${I}_{n}\subset X$, $n\in \mathbf{N}$ ($\mathbf{N}$ are the natural Numbers) be a arbitrary sequence of finite sets and let $K:=\bigcap _{ n\in \mathbf{N}} \bigcup_{ x\in {I }_{ n }} {\overline{{B}_{\frac{1}{n}}(x)}}$

Show that $K$ is compact. (The above should denote closed balls, my edititng is bad)

So in a Metric space the compactness of $K$ is equivalent to K being complete and totally bounded which is equivalent to saying $K$ needs to be closed and totally bounded since closed subsets of complete spaces are complete.
$K$ is obviously closed since the union is finite and finite unions of closed sets are closed and intersection of closed sets is closed.
Now the tricky part for me is showing that $K$ is totally bounded how can i find a finite cover of $K$ consisting of open Balls with radius Epsilon and center in $K$??

Comment: Isn't $K$ contained in $\cup_{x\in I_n}\overline{B_{\frac{1}{n}}(x)}$ which is a finite union of closed balls?

Comment: yes it is but if im not wrong we need open balls to show total boundedness?

Comment: Well how about $$\bigcup_{x\in I_n}B_{\frac{2}{n}}(x)$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We know that a metric space $(X,d)$ is compact if and only if it is complete and totally bounded. That is for every $\varepsilon>0$ there is a finite covering of $X$ by (open) balls of radius $\varepsilon$. Since

$$K = \bigcap_{n\in \mathbf{N}}\underbrace{\bigcup_{x\in I_n}\overline{B_{\frac{1}{n}}(x)}}_{\text{finite union}}$$

it is, as you say, clear that $K$ is closed and therefore also complete. We are now only left to verify total boundedness. We note that for every $n$

$$K\subseteq\bigcup_{x\in I_n}\overline{B_{\frac{1}{n}}(x)}.$$

That is $K$ is covered by finitely many closed balls of radius $1/n$. Show now that it is covered by finitely many OPEN balls of radius $2/n$. Given $\varepsilon$ can we cover $X$ by finitely many balls of radius $\varepsilon$?

Comment: I'm sorry I still struggel a bit with the formalities. intuitively it's clear that we can cover our set with open balls of radius 2/n (drawing a picture of the situation shows it) but how do i show is formally? could u give me small hint? And for your last question i think yes we can because for every Epsilon we can find a finte subet A of X suh that d(x,A)<Epsilon

Comment: What I mean is that $\overline{B_{\frac{1}{n}}(x)}\subseteq B_{\frac{2}{n}(x)}$. The definition of the closure of $B_{\frac{1}{n}}(x)$ is the intersection of all closed sets which contains $B_{\frac{1}{n}}(x)$. Now $$B_{\frac{1}{n}}(x)\subseteq \{y\in X\mid d(x,y)\leq \tfrac{3}{2n}\}\subseteq B_{\frac{2}{n}}(x)$$. The middle set is closed and therefore contains $\overline{B_{\frac{1}{n}}(x)}$ and thus $\overline{B_{\frac{1}{n}}(x)}\subseteq B_{\frac{2}{n}}(x)$. Now given $\varepsilon>0$ let $N$ be chosen  so large that $n>N$ implies that $2/n<\varepsilon$.